# Visual Studio 10: Saxxmlreader undeclared on my Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, msxml6

I have recently switched my PC from Windows 7 to Windows 10. On Windows 7, no problem, my solution is built corectly. But on my Windows 10, with the same solution I have error "SAXXMLReader undeclared". I don't remember have installed anything particular on windows 7, so any idea of why it doesn't works on Windows10?
Can the problem come from a dll of my PC?
Thanks.

EDIT: After some test, here is some details: If I replace the file C:\Windows\System32\msxml6.dll with the msxml6.dll of myWindows 7, I can compile my project and it works! However, Microsoft Excel (for example) doesn't works anymore. So it seems that SAXXMLReader isn't declared anymore in this DLL. Is it a mistake or should I review my code?

Comment: You could try a VS version that isn't totally outdated. Maybe it brings new versions of that dll or maybe the class went into a different dll.

Answer (score 1):

Try SAXXMLReader60. Works for me with VS 2010 on Windows 8

Comment: Note there are subtle differences when moving up to SAXXMLReader60.  For example, the feature "prohibit-dtd" now defaults to TRUE instead of FALSE. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms762317%28v%3dvs.85%29